# Image is not visible after download react JS

Tags: reactjs, image, download

When I click on the download button the image gets download, but when I see the downloaded image the image is not visible can anyone suggest me what to do for this? Can someone this let me know for the same with the example code for react?

Here is the code:

```
function handleDownload() {
 fetch(generateImage)
 .then((response) => {
 if (!response.ok) {
 throw new Error("Failed to download image");
 }
 return response.blob();
 }) 

.then((blob) => { 
const reader = new FileReader();
 reader.onloadend = function() {
 const dataUrl = reader.result;
 const link = document.createElement("a");
 link.href = dataUrl;
 link.download = "generated_image.png";
 link.style.display = "none"; // Hide the line
 document.body.appendChild(link);
 link.click();
 document.body.removeChild(link);
 }; reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
 }) 
.catch((error) => { console.error("Error downloading image:", error); });
```

Comment: function handleDownload() {
    fetch(generateImage)
      .then((response) => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error("Failed to download image");
        }
        return response.blob();
      })

Comment: .then((blob) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function() {
          const dataUrl = reader.result;
          const link = document.createElement("a");
          link.href = dataUrl;
          link.download = "generated_image.png";
          link.style.display = "none"; // Hide the line
          document.body.appendChild(link);
          link.click();
          document.body.removeChild(link);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
      })

Comment: .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error downloading image:", error);
      });

Comment: here is the code.